# Error bound in Laplace method in Zee's QFT book

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

The following is from Zee's 'Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell', 2nd ed., p. 16.

[image]

Can someone please provide a reference and/or intuition for the $e^{-O(h^{1/2})}$ error bound?